# Math mode, gathering terms using braces

Tags: tables, math-mode, braces

How do I produce a result like this without resorting to using a table? to the left of the braces is the result of a function, to the right are the terms (left column) with the conditions (right column)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach is with the `cases` environment from `amsmath`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\bla}{\mathit{bla}}
\begin{document}
\[\bla =
\begin{cases}
    \bla, & n < 0\\
    \bla^2. & n = 0\\
    \bla^{-1}, & n > 0.
\end{cases}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

There are a few different environments you can use here:

- `cases` sets both columns in text-style math mode.
- `cases*` from the `mathtools` package sets the first column in math mode, and the second column in text mode.
- `dcases` (also from `mathtools`) uses display-style math instead. This is useful if one of your definitions has an integral or a fraction in it.
- Finally, `dcases*` (also from `mathtools`) sets the first column in display-style math, and the second in text mode.

Answer (score 4):

This is a *case* (pun ;-) for one of the various `cases` environments, e.g. `dcases` from `mathtools` or just `cases` (already in `amsmath`)

The relevant text should be put in proper `\text{...}` command, but this has been omitted here

I used `dcases` for nicer display (d stands for `displaymath` here)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\[
 f = \begin{dcases}
   a & bla \\
   c & blabla \\
   e & blabla \\
   \end{dcases}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]